# How to use photo after snapshot? ios7

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios7, camera

I can not test my app on iPhone now, so I am need some help.
I writer simple camera app. I need that, when user makes snapshot - this photo will goes to my app. I use default camera interface.

```
- (IBAction)cameraButtonAction:(id)sender {
self.newPhoto = YES;
[self continueWithSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];

}

- (void)continueWithSourceType: (UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType
{
UIImagePickerController * imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
imagePickerController.delegate = self;
imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType;
imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
imagePickerController.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];

if ([imagePickerController.mediaTypes isEqual: @[(NSString *) kUTTypeMovie]])
{
}
if (sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)
{
    imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = YES;
}
//cam

self.imagePickerController = imagePickerController;
[self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

So I need that users snapshot will be saved in self.image:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
UIImage * image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
if (self.newPhoto)
{
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
}
//cam
self.image = image;
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

But if user will make 2 or 3 photo? And how he can back to my app?

Comment: Using the above code, the user doesn't leave your app. Your question is unclear. The above code only lets the user take one photo at a time. Your app will process each photo one at a time.

Comment: thanks, that is function that I need now

Comment: `UIImagePickerController` only allows for one photo at a time.

Comment: @rmaddy, What I need to add some code to give to user ability to take more then 1 photo and then pick the 1, which will be goes to self.image?

Comment: You to show the user the image picker once for each photo. Let them take photos until they cancel. Then show them a screen with all of the images they just took and let them pick one. None of this built in. You need to write all of that code.